# Login System with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been working with this code forever but cannot figure out what's wrong.

It logs in okay but it does not pass the id into the session.  It works with JQuery.

```
$loginresult = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$loginresult->bindParam(":username", $username);
$loginresult->bindParam(":password", $encryptedPassword);
$loginresult->execute();
$result = $loginresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($loginresult !== false){
       $_SESSION['loggedin'] = microtime();
       $_SESSION['userid'] = $result->id;
       echo 'true';
}else{
      echo 'false';
}
```

EDIT: New Code

```
<?php
require('../../config.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$encryptedPassword = crypt($password,$salt);

$loginresult = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$loginresult->bindParam(":username", $username);
$loginresult->bindParam(":password", $encryptedPassword);
$loginresult->execute();
$count = $loginresult->rowCount();
        var_dump($count);
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
if($count){
        $result = $loginresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        var_dump($result);
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
        session_start();
       $_SESSION['loggedin'] = microtime();
       $_SESSION['userid'] = $result->id;
       echo $result->id;
       //echo 'true';
}else{
      echo 'false';
}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `$result` for `false`, not `$loginresult`? `$loginresult` is your `PDOStatement` object. Also, as @jeroen states, you need `session_start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
if($loginresult){
```

instead of:

```
if($loginresult !== true){
```

Note that `fetch` only returns `false` in case of a failure.

And of course you need `session_start();` before any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: Oh sorry. That was a typo when copying the text over to Stack Overflow. Still won't give the id :/

Comment: Good fix. But $result->id still returns nothing.

Comment: @user2059490 You need to clarify what the problem is: Does the session variable not get set or is your `$result` variable empty? What is the result of `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: It comes back bool(false). The session only works if I set it manually. It should use the id from the db call

Comment: @user2059490 You should add error handling to your database calls (all of them), that will probably tell you what is wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: I have done that. It comes back with Array( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) which does not make sense. It will echo true or false but is null otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Array( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )  the first element of the array is the error code. it means there is no error for the query. if it echoes nothing. you may need to comment the codes of setting session. I guess the problem is the search result is empty, the $result is null, so $result->id will get a php error, which makes the echo is not executed.

Comment: Yeah I got that but the record exists.. and it comes back true. And comes back false if its wrong. That's where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: if($loginresult !== false). i think you should use if($result !== false)